# Travelling from Venice to Budapest, making a stop in Croatia

Tags: schengen, europe, croatia

I booked a flixbus from Venice to Budapest, however it makes a stop in Zagreb, Croatia for an hour and ten minutes and I only have access to the Schengen area. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Is your Schengen visa single-entry or multiple-entry?

Comment: If there is a problem, it's because of entering Croatia at all: stopping or not stopping wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Your status will likely be checked, when the bus will cross the border. You probably will not make it into Zagreb at all. They can hardly lock you into the bus until they eventually leave Croatia.

Comment: Was working on an answer when this was closed: "I only have access to the Schengen area": If this is true, then yes, you have a problem.  When the bus reaches the Croatian border, you will be removed from the bus.  (Bus travel is generally unlike air travel in this regard; the entire bus clears border controls at the physical border; most train travel is like this, too.)  [par] However, some Schengen visas *allow the bearer to enter Croatia.*  If you have such a visa, then you are incorrect about not "having access" to Croatia, and you do not have a problem.

Comment: I don't understand why JoErNanO closed this question. It seems fair and obvious enough for me. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Agreed. Sure, we don't know what Schengen visa the asker has but, as I understand it, the answer is, essentially, "If you have a multiple-entry Schengen visa, you're fine; if you have single-entry, you're not." (Please do **not** take that statement as true! I'm not an expert on this!) That kind of answer can be written easily without knowing what kind of visa the asker has and it's actually more useful, since it means that somebody with the other kind of visa won't need to ask the same question again next month.

Comment: Voting for re-open as well. This is a entirely valid travel question.

Comment: I am surprised to not find anything on Flixbus' FAQ at all about visa requirements for international travel.

Comment: Just checked the VISA requirements for Croatia at their ministry's website: http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/. Basically you have two choices. If you have a multiple-entry VISA for the Schengen area, you will be fine but it will count as one entrry. So if you have only a dual entry, be careful. Besides thar as you are not saying where you are from it might be that you can enter Croatia without a visa, but then again, you will use up one Schengen entry when crossing the border from Croatia to Hungary.

Comment: @TorstenS please don't write "visa" in all caps.  It's distracting, and it implies that the word is an acronym, which it is not.

Answer (score 13):

The question has basically already been answered in the comments, but here we go, also with a few possibilities to solve the problem.

If you are correct with your statement in the question, that you are not allowed to enter Croatia, you will only have a single-entry Schengen visa. In this case, you will neither be allowed to take the bus from Venice to Zagreb, nor would you be allowed to take the bus from Zagreb to Budapest if you still somehow managed to reach Zagreb. To travel from Zagreb to Budapest, you would reenter the Schengen area and since your single-entry visa has already been 'used up', you would not be let in a second time.

If you still want to travel with FlixBus, you have at least two other options:

- There are direct buses from Venice to Budapest. As far as I can find out, all of them go via Ljubljana and Maribor, so you will stay within the Schengen area for the entire trip and be safe. I might have overseen some exception here, so please verify with FlixBus that you are good if you decide to book one of these.
- There are also connections with a transfer in Vienna. These are definitely staying within the Schengen area for the entire trip, so these are 'safe'.

I can't find any prices online, but there is at least one daily and reasonable train connection from Venice (departing 09:55) to Budapest (20:19) with a transfer in Vienna. Also this connection will stay within the Schengen area.

If you actually have a multi-entry Schengen visa, and as Torsten S already pointed out enough entries left to use, you are actually allowed to enter Croatia with your current Schengen visa and the trip you have booked is not a problem at all.